# Why Is my computer screen not turning on and DVDs drive keeps trying to play a disk

Tags: boot, hard-drive, screen, drive

When I turn on my computer the cylinder light for hard drive flashes at the same time as the dvd drive light flashes. The screen works intermittently but it never goes past anything but the starting screen that appears as soon as you press power. Also the dad drive is trying to read a disk

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any disk inside the drive? If you do, the system may be configured to boot from the drive, and when you boot, it reads the DVD and, as there's nothing to boot from, the computer doesn't start.

**Next time you click on the power button, open the drive and check if there's anything inside it.**

If not, it may be a BIOS or GRUB malfunction. *But that's risky to modify*. If done incorrectly, you may cause bigger problems to your PC.

Comment: How can I open the drive if it isn't starting?

Comment: Normally, when the PC is running, even when the OS doesn't work, every piece of hardware is turned on. If the drive doesn't open, then it may not be a software problem. It may be in hardware, the power supply may be broken and the PC doesn't work correctly. First turn on the PC and check if you can open the drive. If not, it's better to have the PC checked by someone that understands about hardware ;)

Comment: Ok I just don't know how to open the drive at all

Comment: I'll try to figure it put

Comment: Don't force the drive to open, you may damage the engine that opens and closes it

Comment: The computer is really old and sucks and also it was having this problem with no disk in it and then I tried to put one in and it took it and won't give it back

Comment: Well, i can't help anymore, i don't have the knowledge to solve this. Sorry, i did what i could